# JavaFX drag and drop for internal communications

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, scenebuilder

So, when I click on the image (the source), as soon as I begin to drag the image, the size of the image triples "while" I'm dragging it, util I drop it in the target. (It then resizes to the correct size).

my guess is the image on the Dragboard or Clipboard should be modified, yet I don't see any API/method that does it.

I thought of having a smaller image, yet the size still triples while on drag.

Also I am using scene builder.

```
public class Controller {

    public ImageView targetImageView;
    public ImageView sourceImageView;


    public void handleDragDetected(MouseEvent dd) {
        Dragboard db = 
        sourceImageView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
        ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
        clipboardContent.putImage(sourceImageView.getImage());
        db.setContent(clipboardContent);
        dd.consume();
    }

    public void handleDragOver(DragEvent dragEvent) {
        if ( dragEvent.getDragboard().hasImage() )
            dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.ANY);

    }

    public void handleOnDragDropped(DragEvent dragEvent) {
        Image img = dragEvent.getDragboard().getImage();
        targetImageView.setImage(img);
    }
}
```

I do not get any errors, just an undesirable look.